# What is the event for product view?

Tags: magento2, product

I want to save the customer_id and the product_id in a table after clicking a product and seeing its detail
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product view controller triggers an event you can use:

catalog_controller_product_view

See vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product/View.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_controller_product_view', ['product' => $product]);
```